# create javascript tree out of list of objects

Tags: javascript, tree

I would like to 'translate' a list of objects into a json format edible by jstree:

```
data = [
    { 
        "data" : { 
            "title" : "father",
            "attr" : { "href" : "#" }
        },
        "children" : [
            { 
                "data" : { 
                    "title" : "Older Son",
                    "attr" : { "href" : "#" }
                },
                "children" : []
            },
            { 
                "data" : { 
                    "title" : "Younger Son",
                    "attr" : { "href" : "#" }
                },
                "children" : []
            }
        ]
    },
]
```

My input looks like this:

```
[
Object
id: 35
name: "bnm,bnm"
parent_id: null
, 
Object
id: 36
name: "ghk"
parent_id: 35
, 
Object
id: 37
name: "hgkgh"
parent_id: null
, 
Object
id: 38
name: "jklhjk"
parent_id: null
, 
Object
id: 39
name: "fghdfgh"
parent_id: 38
, 
Object
id: 40
name: "bsdbd"
parent_id: 38
,
...]
```

Well, to be honest, this would not be a tree, rather a forest. But it doesn't matter.

I've spent quite a lot of time on it, but failed to get it working. Operating on arrays seems to be nasty in javascript (in comparison to Java,C++ or PHP)...

What I've tried so far is:

1. (pre) the source data (list of objects) meet one condition: a son can't be present before it's parent
2. make it associative array (key=id, value=object), so it had to be string-keyed.
3. pop last array element and push it inside its parent element's children array. Repeat this for all non-null-parent elements.
4. hoped this should work.

Comment: Please post what you have tried so far. It might make it easier for us to help you.

Comment: I find PHP arrays nastier than JavaScript arrays. JS is very lean. What are you trying to do and what didn't work, I don't quite get it...

Comment: I've edited my post and described the algorithm idea. I know I should write on stacoverflow what I've tried so far -but I'm not experienced in JS and my code looked so ugly that it could make no sense to paste it here :/...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You'll want to first put all of your items into a sparse array indexed by their ID and translate everything except the children (which should be present but empty) and including the parent ID:

```
var itemsByID = [];
items.forEach(function(item) {
    itemsByID[item.id] = {
        data: {title: item.name},
        children: [],
        parentID: item.parent_id
    };
});
```

Then you'll want to go through all of the items, adding children to their parents:

```
itemsByID.forEach(function(item) {
    if(item.parentID !== null) {
        itemsByID[item.parentID].children.push(item);
    }
});
```

Then find the roots:

```
var roots = itemsByID.filter(function(item) { return item.parentID === null; });
```

Then clean the items up by removing the parent ID:

```
itemsByID.forEach(function(item) { delete item.parentID; });
```

The roots of the tree will be in `roots`.

---

The reason your method didn't work is that if any children have a parent with a greater ID number, the parent element will not exist; you have already processed and popped it. You must leave all items in the array until you're done.

Comment: For simplicity, I am using a number of methods of arrays that may not be available in older browsers. These methods can be safely shimmed or the code modified to not use these methods.

Comment: well, I've tried your algorithm, but I don't like that JS inserts undefined into "holes" in the array (in fact, I wanted a typical map structure in the intermediate phase). So I decided to create a string-keyed array.

Comment: @tkoomzaaskz: It's not array-specific. Accessing a nonexistent property on an object yields `undefined`. Furthermore, properties on all objects (including arrays) are string-keyed; it's just that the array's properties are string representations of the numbers. (When you do `a[b]` with an integer `b`, it is coerced into a string.)

Comment: maybe my chrome javascript console made me think the array is different than it really is (and this led me to think that it fills holes with undefined). Anyway, thanks a lot!

Comment: @tkoomzaaskz: Well, it kind of does; the holes aren't necessarily represented in memory, but they could be. It doesn't matter, since it'll be `undefined` if it's explicitly set to `undefined` or it'll be set to `undefined` if it's not explicitly defined.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe [unsplay](https://github.com/dbkaplun/unsplay) does the trick?

```
>> var unsplay = require('unsplay');
>> unsplay([{id: 0}, {id: 1, pid: 0}], 'id', 'pid');
[{
  item: {id: 0},
  children: [{
    item: {id: 1, pid: 0},
    children: []
  }]
}]
```

(DISCLAIMER: I am the author)